# how define a image in listview android?

Tags: android, image, listview

I have a layout with this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   style="@style/fundo"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/consoleListaSimples"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listaSimples"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

and for which item from the list a have this xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:background="@drawable/bk_principal_small">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imagemStatus"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/green"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/texto1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/padrao" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and to create the itens I create a *SimpleAdapter* that I insert the data using the method *ListAdapterCreater*

```
this.adapter = new ListAdapterCreater(list.getContext(),itensList,
R.layout.list_simple_item,new String[] {"text","image"},
            new int[]{R.id.texto1,R.id.imagemStatus});
```

to set the text works pretty, but doesn`t work for the image.
what have to be the value of *image*? or what should I change to works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the below links which have sample code snippets.

[LINK1](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter)  it has one textview and one  image view in each list item.

[LINK2](http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/) it has two textview in each list item.

[LINK3](http://www.softwarepassion.com/android-series-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/)  it has two textview and one  image view in each list item.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you'll have to create new Adapter that extends `BaseAdapter`.

Here's a few tutorials for you:

- http://blog.sptechnolab.com/2011/02/01/android/android-custom-listview-items-and-adapters/
- http://w2davids.wordpress.com/android-listview-with-iconsimages-and-sharks-with-lasers/

If you look closely on those tutorials, the trick lies in how `getView()` work.